# HtmlAttributes not working for boolean property ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, checkbox, editorfor

I've a model with a boolean property:

```
public bool IsWorking{ get; set; }
```

In the view I'm using:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.IsWorking, new BaseAdditionalData() { HtmlAttributes = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "id", "IsWorkingCustom" }, { "name", "IsWorkingCustom" } } })
```

but the rendered HTML of the checkbox contains `id="IsWorking" name="IsWorking"`, so nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to change `name` to `Name` so:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.IsWorking, new BaseAdditionalData { HtmlAttributes = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "id", "IsWorkingCustom" }, { "Name", "IsWorkingCustom" } } })
```